# Is it possible to set an Upstart service to stop $LAST

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, init.d, init

I'm wanting the rsyslog service to run until the last moment to ensure we receive as much logging as possible on our central logging servers.  On Ubuntu 11.04, rsyslog's stop line is set to "stop on runlevel [06]" so it stops before (at least) services stopped via rc0.d/K scripts.  How can I achieve the equivalent of /etc/rc0.d/K99rsyslog?

Comment: If the [K script is of the highest number](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html), it should die in that order.  You should be able to adjust the rc files to reflect the order as:  `/etc/rc0.d/K99rsyslog` and `/etc/rc6.d/K99rsyslog` to take care proc kill handling of both Halt and Restart states.

Comment: I failed to mention that rsyslog is an Upstart service in Ubuntu 11.04 so it doesn't have ha K script.

Comment: [Take a look at this page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#shutdown-process), which seems to detail that usage of K scripts.

Comment: The problem isn't with the usage of K scripts but Upstart stopping rsyslog before K scripts running/completing.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that once the networking is taken down, rsyslog will most likely cease to function, so just terminating the operation LAST may not have the desired effect (if any).

Comment: I'm fine with it being at that point as long as the other rc0.d/K scripts have run.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to disable the shutdown of rsyslog altogether. To do this I commented out the stop line in /etc/init/rsyslog.conf and then  and  as init didn't automatically pick up the change nor did  update it.

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this method for all use cases.  This was for systems that are short lived - Auto Scaled Amazon EC2 instances that are spun up as needed then terminated.